# Numpy for-loop runtime too long

Tags: arrays, numpy, runtime

I have a problem with the runtime of my code. The only module that is really slow is my for-loop over every matrix element in a (144, 208)-array.

I have to check every element if the condition is fulfilled and if so, i have to perform several actions like shifting another (144, 208)-array and add it to an existing one.

Is this not changeable or is my implementation way too beginner-like?

Here is my code:

```
# With this codeblock i am loading a specific image into python and 
binarize it
g = Initialization()
b_init = g.initialize_grid(".\\geometries\\1.png")

# this function will modify the matrix m_sp, which i load in as csv.file
def expand_blockavg(x, h, w):
    m, n = x.shape
    return np.broadcast_to((x/float(h*w))[:, None, :, None], (m, h, n, w)).reshape(m*h, -1)
    m_adapt = expand_blockavg(m_sp, 16, 16) / 256

# This is my actual calculation block
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(b_init):
    if x == 1:
        a = np.asarray(index)
        y = np.subtract(a, index_default)
        m_shift = shift(m_adapt, (y[0], y[1]), cval=0)
        b = np.add(m_shift, b)
```

SO, the last block (calculation) is what takes so long. I know that the loop has to check 30k elements. But i thought that with numpy it will be faster.

Can some1 tell me if there's potential for optimization or do i have to live with the fact that it'll take so long.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iteration in python is very slow compared to vectorized numpy operations.

An immediate optimization is to only iterate over the indices where the matrix is 1, rather than checking each index. Do this with:

```
indices = np.argwhere(b_init == 1)
for a in indices:
    y = np.array(a) - index_default
    m_shift = shift(m_adapt, y[:2], cval=0)
    b += m_shift
```

Not knowing the details of shift it’s hard to say if you can vectorize that also. I replaced function calls with equivalent operations which should be faster; np.add etc. are mostly useful when the operation is being selected programmatically.